# aws-sdk for Lambda not up to date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda

I use a `node4.3` `Lambda Function` triggered by a `custom resource` in my `CloudFormation` `json` that requires the latest `aws-sdk` to be able to call

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
```

But it looks like the `aws-sdk` is not the latest since it errors and I can see in the logs that `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` is undefined.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html
`CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` is not supported yet

[image]

> Note: Although all services are supported in the browser version of
>   the SDK, not all of the services are available in the default hosted
>   build (using the script tag provided above). A list of services in the
>   hosted build are provided in the "Working With Services" section of
>   the browser SDK guide, including instructions on how to build a custom
>   version of the SDK with extra services.

Comment: Oh, that is too bad since it makes it impossible to create Cognito User Pools with CloudFormation. So I cannot automatically create my whole environment with CloudFormation :( Any idea when it will be updated (either the aws-sdk or Cognito support in CloudFormation)?

Comment: I was trying with local node-sdk 2.3.3 and i upgraded to 2.3.5 and it worked, if that is happening, i guess you can try to upload the bundled zip file to lambda and then run it.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try that. Always wondered what would be the right way to override the default aws-sdk on Lambda Servers with a specific (newer) version. Bundling up with webpack seems like a good way to do it - only that is a lot of work for me to integrate bundling into the serverless framework.